# C# Deleting a customer from its ID

Tags: c#, class, methods

Hi there I was wondering if its possible for me to create a method in my customer.cs to delete a customer depending on its ID. How I want this to work is that the user will select a customer from the list box which only shows the customers firstName and then hit delete which will delete the customer off the list box. But I want to somehow create a method in the customer.cs which will look at the ID then delete it if its the right one. Can this be done? Any help would be create thank you.

form.cs:

```
public partial class AddCustomer : Form
{

    List<Customer> list = new List<Customer>();
    Random rand = new Random();


    public AddCustomer()
    {
        InitializeComponent();


    }

   // Adds Customer
    private void buttonAddCustomer_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
  
        Customer customer = new Customer();
        customer.customerId = rand.Next();
        customer.firstName = textBoxfn.Text;

        list.Add(customer);
        listBoxCustomers.Items.Add(customer.firstName);


    }

    // Deletes Customer
    private void buttonDeleteCustomer_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        listBoxCustomers.Items.Remove(listBoxCustomers.SelectedItem);

   
    }
  }
 }
```

Customer.cs:

```
 public class Customer
  {
    public int customerId;
    public string firstName;
    public string lastName;
    public string phoneNumber;
    public string address;

    public string FirstName
    {
        get { return firstName; }
        set { firstName = value; }
    }

    public string LastName
    {
        get { return lastName; }
        set { lastName = value; }
    }

    public string PhoneNumber
    {
        get { return phoneNumber; }
        set { phoneNumber = value; }
    }

    public string Address
    {
        get { return address; }
        set { address = value; }
    }

 }
}
```

Comment: How will the method know it the right one? It will be the one selected...what other criteria would there be?

Comment: Im not sure. Ive just been told it needs to delete the selected customer but I need to make a method in the customer.cs that will delete it by its ID not firstName.

Comment: If you have to use a listBox...you need to make the selection ID + ":" + Name...or something and then parse the ID out. Just use a dropdown where you have textfield and valuefield.

Answer (score 1):

One idea is to load your customer list into a `BindingList<Customer>`

Now with this approach you work from the BindingList and the selected index of the ListBox.

I used a pre-defined customer class I had.

```
public class Customer
{
    public int CustomerIdentifier { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Street { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string PostalCode { get; set; }
    public int CountryIdentifier { get; set; }

    public override string ToString() => $"{FirstName} {LastName}";
}
```

**Mocked data**

```
public class MockedData
{
    public static List<Customer> Customers() => new List<Customer>()
    {
        new Customer()
        {
            CustomerIdentifier = 1, FirstName = "Jim", LastName = "Adams",
            Street = "120 Hanover Sq.", City = "London", PostalCode = "WA1 1DP", 
            CountryIdentifier = 19
        },
        new Customer()
        {
            CustomerIdentifier = 2, FirstName = "Mary", LastName = "Adams",
            Street = "1 rue Alsace-Lorraine", City = "Toulouse", PostalCode = "31000", 
            CountryIdentifier = 8
        },
        new Customer()
        {
            CustomerIdentifier = 3, FirstName = "Karen", LastName = "White",
            Street = "120 Hanover Sq.", City = "London", PostalCode = "WA1 1DP", 
            CountryIdentifier = 19
        }
    };
}
```

**Form code**

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private readonly BindingList<Customer> _customersBindingList;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        _customersBindingList = new BindingList<Customer>(MockedData.Customers());
        listBoxCustomers.DataSource = _customersBindingList;
    }

    private void RemoveCurrentButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (listBoxCustomers.SelectedIndex > -1)
        {
            _customersBindingList.RemoveAt(listBoxCustomers.SelectedIndex);
        }

        RemoveCurrentButton.Enabled = listBoxCustomers.SelectedIndex > -1;
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is the function to remove all customers with a certain id :

```
private void RemoveCustomer(int id)
{
    list.RemoveAll(c => c.customerId == id);
}
```

Comment: Thank you. How would I add this into my code?

Comment: You can call this function in your `buttonDeleteCustomer_Click` function, of just copy paste the `RemoveAll` instruction inside it.

Comment: Ok thank you ill try that. Also when I add the RemoveCustomer method into the customer.cs it has a error at list. it says the name 'list' does not exist in the current context. How do I fix that?

Comment: list is your variable defined here: `List<Customer> list = new List<Customer>();`. I don't know what you are doing wrong when copying this line since I don't know you `customer.cs` file.

Comment: I was wanting the function to be put in the customer.cs not the form.cs

Comment: @HarryB  I _suppose_ you could create a `static` method in the `Customer` class that takes in both a `List<Customer>` and the ID of all instances of `Customer` to remove from that list.  But this seems like something the `Customer` class shouldn't need to manage.  Ultimately the list state is managed by the Form, not by an instance of `Customer`.